# use jQuery to paginate JSON data?

Tags: jquery, json

How to show only 10 items per page in accord with the url query? For example, show data from `../?_page=1` on click "page 1", show data from `../?_page=2` on click "page 2" etc

```
<div id="container">demo</div>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/",
            // success
            success : function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $('#container').html('');
                $.each(data,function(i,d){

                    $('#container').append('<p>'+d.albumId+'</p>');
                    $('#container').append('<p>'+d.id+'</p>');
                    $('#container').append('<p>'+d.title+'</p>');
                    $('#container').append('<p>'+d.url+'</p>');
                    $('#container').append('<hr/>');
                })
            },
            // error
            error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you can use jquery datatable, https://datatables.net/, it gives automatic pagination

Comment: is it got any better manual way instead using tat plugin? btw thanks for your reply :)

Comment: afcoz manual pagination is quite difficult, this plugin does it all itself